# Random crashes with only blinking cursor at the top left

Tags: linux, debian, logs, crash

I've seen a lot of posts about a blinking cursor on boot, or after install, but not at random times.

Lately I've had two annoying crashes while doing nothing more than browsing the web. This time I can only remember I was watching a YouTube video. At the same time the sound stopped and screen went out, going to text mode with nothing more than a blinking cursor at the top left. System load was low (both CPU, memory and disk). I don't usually have high temperatures, and the fan was not at a high speed. It's a new laptop with Debian 12, a fresh install from 1 month ago. This same computer works fine with Windows 11 and on Windows it gets a higher load. Memtest86 and memtester don't show any errors, and the S.M.A.R.T. information about the hard disk looks fine

I check the system log (with `journalctl`) and can find nothing there. Where could I find logs about the crash or more information about what does it mean when the system crashes with a blinking cursor?

**EDIT:**

It looks like a problem with the hard disk, however `badblocks` and SMART don't show any errors

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to check all of the logs

```
/var/log/
```

And look for something with the same timestamp when the system 'hangs/crashes'.

Another thing could be an issue with the video card, I would set up SSH. Then next time the laptop does this, see if you can SSH into the laptop. That could be a way to troubleshoot if the issue has to do with rendering the display.

In that case, you could try another desktop UI or look at different drivers for the video card. Also, you could look at another DISTRO.

Comment: Thanks... I tried and I can't SSH into the laptop

Answer (score 0):

I had some system files in a external USB SSD that had random disconnections, most probably it was because of that.